# C: Initializing a struct and assigning it to pointer in function parameter

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

Because of an assignment at Uni, I face the weird problem of having to initialize a struct to a pointer provided as a function parameter. Everything appears fine inside of that init function, but once I try to access the objects's values inside a different function, they just appear to be empty.

As I'm horrible at explaining things, I got a small example with actual and expected output:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo {
    int bar;
};

void init_foo(struct foo* f) {
    f = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
    f->bar = 5;
    printf("bar0: %d\n", f->bar);
}

void print_foo(struct foo* f) {
    printf("bar1: %d\n", f->bar);
}

int main() {
    struct foo f;
    init_foo(&f);
    print_foo(&f);
}
```

Acutal output:

```
bar0: 5
bar1: 0
```

Expected output:

```
bar0: 5
bar1: 5
```

I haven't dealt with C all that much before, so if someone could provide an explanation and/or a solution to this, I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `main()`, `f` is an allocated version of the `foo` struct. You passed a pointer to that allocated structure to `init_foo()`.

There is no need for `f` to be `malloc()`'ed inside of `init_foo()`. `f` already points to an allocated structure.

I think if you just remove the `malloc()`, it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much :) 
(You were the first one to answer this, so I'll accept as soon as I can)

Comment: "*You were the first one to answer this*" - only by 7 seconds ;-)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Gotta support the newcomers :P

Comment: Ha. Thanks.  I've been writing "C" for way too long. I think my favorite language is PHP these days.

Comment: @HenryF I should have accepted the other answer then. What a monster would favor PHP over anything?!

Answer (score 2):

You need to get rid of the `malloc()`, it doesn't belong since `main()` already allocated memory for its local `f` variable.  `init_foo()` just needs to populate the existing memory.  By calling `malloc()`, you are changing the `foo*` pointer inside of `init_foo()` to point at different memory, ignoring the original memory that was passed in.

Try this instead:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo {
    int bar;
};

void init_foo(struct foo* f) {
    f->bar = 5;
    printf("bar0: %d\n", f->bar);
}

void print_foo(struct foo* f) {
    printf("bar1: %d\n", f->bar);
}

int main() {
    struct foo f;
    init_foo(&f);
    print_foo(&f);
}
```

On the other hand, if you want `init_foo()` to allocate memory for the struct, then do this instead:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo {
    int bar;
};

void init_foo(struct foo** f) {
    *f = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
    if (f) {
        (*f)->bar = 5;
        printf("bar0: %d\n", (*f)->bar);
    }
}

void free_foo(struct foo* f) {
    free(f);
}

void print_foo(struct foo* f) {
    printf("bar1: %d\n", f->bar);
}

int main() {
    struct foo *f;
    init_foo(&f);
    if (f) {
        print_foo(f);
        free_foo(f);
    }
}
```

Or this:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo {
    int bar;
};

struct foo* init_foo() {
    struct foo *f = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
    if (f) {
        f->bar = 5;
        printf("bar0: %d\n", f->bar);
    }
    return f;
}

void free_foo(struct foo* f) {
    free(f);
}

void print_foo(struct foo* f) {
    printf("bar1: %d\n", f->bar);
}

int main() {
    struct foo *f = init_foo(&f);
    if (f) {
        print_foo(f);
        free_foo(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional knowledge, but just removing the malloc was sufficient in my case :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't `malloc` inside `init_foo`; space was already allocated by the caller.  So you're filling up the space you `malloc`ed, but *not* the space pointed to by the pointer passed to the function.

Answer (score 1):

You are eclipsing struct foo* f.

You have a stack based structure struct foo f defined in main. You pass a pointer to it, to the init_foo function. However you then immediately replace that structure pointer with an allocated structure, and proceed to fill that structure in. The original struct foo* f which was passed into the init_foo function was therefore not modified.

You then leak the memory by exiting the init_foo function and then you print the uninitilized structure.

You do not need the memory allocation, remove it all. Simply initialize directly into the struct foo* f you pass into the init_foo function.